# Xamarin toolbar item on IOS not aligning properly

Tags: ios, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am having difficulty in aligning a toolbar item to the far right on the IOS build of a Xamarin application, although, on the Android build, it works perfectly fine and aligns the toolbar item to the far right of the toolbar.

XML code for the toolbar item:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems x:Uid="ToolbarName">
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="Settings" Order="Primary" Icon="cog.png" Priority="0" Clicked="Settings_Clicked" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

IOS build toolbar:

[image]

I do not want to change the XML too much as I am worried that it will then effect the android build.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Still an issue for iOS with the latest MAUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3513) of the Xamarin ToolbarItems, you could try update you Xamarin Forms version to see if the issue was fixed.

A workaround would be using a NavigationPage.TitleView ([source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/158557/xamarin-forms-how-to-align-the-contentpage-toolbar-image-to-center))

```
<ContentPage>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="10" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <Image Source="cog.png">               
            </Image>           
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did see this through investigation behind the matter, in hindsight, I should have stated that in my question. I will give it a bash and let you know. THanks!

Comment: @fluffy i edited my anwser, it should be VerticalOptions="End" (or EndAndExpand), and not "Center"

Comment: Thanks! Gonna give it a bash now.

Comment: Thanks, it has helped, i edited your answer to align the item to the complete right.