# Graphical issues in IOS toolbar header

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm developing a mobile application with Xamarin.Forms and Prism framework.
This is the code of my application header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="MyApplication.Views.MainPage"
             Title="MyApplication">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="settings.png" Command="{Binding TapSettingsCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="mylogo.gif" Command="{Binding TapLogoCommand}" />        
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

In Android version all is ok:

[image: Android application header]

But in IOS version I have some issues:

[image: IOS application header]

Images are totally white and not aligned to the right.
How can I solve these graphical issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and reported [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3513).

The workaround is to use a `NavigationPage.TitleView` instead .

```
<ContentPage>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            <ImageButton Source="settings.png" Command="{Binding TapSettingsCommand}"/>
            <ImageButton Source="mylogo.gif" Command="{Binding TapLogoCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
</ContentPage>
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501197/8187800.